# Firefox use another charset when send form

Tags: firefox, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I have problem with Firefox browser. On page I have "form" and when I submit this "form" then my webpage change charset from "utf-8" to "Windows-1250". When I go to another place in page then charset go back to "utf-8". This problem is only in Firefox in another browser works everything fine (Chrome, Opera, IE - I can check this in Safari etc..)
I search on internet a lot of time, but I found nothing. Some way is via Ajax or change something in Firefox or get some plugin, but I need solution which can work for everyone without change something in browser. Because clients must have correct default charset => no some "alert" with information what they must change on their pc. I have Firefox 27.0.1.

I have this codes:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="cs" />
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="poslat.html" onsubmit="this.action=''; return kontrola_udaju_vlozit_inzerat(this);" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Attribute "accept-charset" don´t help me. And all of pages (php, js) are in UTF-8. I have this problem on 3 sites (I mean) and this type of problem have some peoples on internet and for that I mean this is Firefox bug but I need solved it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you infer that the encoding is changed to Windows-1250? Does it happen on form submission (how?), or are you referring to the way that the *server response* is shown? Where can be see that response (with HTTP headers)?

Comment: Hi when I send form then I can see information text. "Váš inzerát byl v pořádku vložen." = text with Czech chars. But in Firefox I see "VĂˇĹˇ inzerĂˇt byl v poĹ™Ăˇdku vloĹľen." and all thing on my page (header, footer etc..) and every texts change to this "text" where Czech chars change to something ugly. And windows-1250 I see in Firefox setting. On every page I see UTF-8 but after send form I see here windows-1250.

Comment: I can send link to my form, but this place add advertisement to the bazaar and for that I prefere not test it on whole internet.

Comment: So it’s apparently the server response that is shown as windows-1250. The probable reason is that this is the default encoding that Firefox uses, and it uses it because the server response does not specify the encoding, in HTTP headers or in a `meta` tag or with BOM. You need to change the server side code so that it specifies the encoding in at least one of these ways.

Comment: I talk about server with my chief and he said this is not problem, because form in our another sites work fine in Firefox and this site (where I have problem with form) was created in the same way. If we have problem on server then this problem must be on every page and we have this problem on maybe on 3 sites he said.

Comment: Did your boss actually check the response page and its HTTP headers? Unless you can give some relevant facts to work on, there is little hope of finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround /not a solution/ :
redirect to specified url instead of displaying the same page after form submit

just a few minutes later found solution:
I added a line to htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

works :) in my page

Comment: You simply add this line after some line with "RewriteRule" etc. ? I have this problem on page where I can´t test a lot of times. For that I need test this code one times and after that say "this work" or "not work" and delete this line.